# List all outgoing REST calls made from my angular app

Tags: angularjs, url, web-crawler

I have a angular application running locally. It calls n other endpoints internally to other services and fetches the data as and when user navigates.
I want a list of all such REST endpoints used within the application.
Is there any tool or scanner I can use.

Comment: If you use http to query the services, then the request should show up in the network tab in your browser.

Comment: Agreed, But in that case i have to click every button and visit every link from webpage.What i want is list of urls being used in the source code without actually visting or completing the ops. There are hundreds of calls being made currently